# Compare Date to constant using ACE.OLEDB.12 in Excel VBA

Tags: 2010, list, excel, query, vba

After a lot of searching, trial and error, I finally managed to come up with an Excel VBA procedure that will return date from a SharePoint list.  The query works fine if I do not qualify the Select or if I compare a field with a constant (string or numeric).  Unfortunately, my users want to see records with a Production Date greater than a specified date.  I have tried:

```
Select * from <LIST NAME> where [Production Date] > CAST('01/01/2013', DATE)
```

this returns a run time error 1004.  Any help in getting this to work would be greatly appreciated.  The full procedure follows:

```
Sub y()

   Dim strConnection As String
   Dim strSQL As String
   Dim qt As QueryTable

   ActiveSheet.Select
   Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

   strConnection = "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=1;RetrieveIds=Yes;" _
& "DATABASE=http://SITE_NAME_HERE/;" _
& "LIST={79632D8F-E6E9-4645-8AD6-C025167FB7ED};"

  strSQL = "SELECT * FROM LIST_NAME_HERE where [Production Date] > cast('06/15/2013' as date)"

  Set qt = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=Array(strConnection),Destination:=Range ("a1"), Sql:=strSQL)

  With qt
     .CommandText = Array(strSQL) 
     .Name = "Data from SP list"
     .FieldNames = True
     .RowNumbers = False
     .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
     .PreserveFormatting = True
     .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
     .BackgroundQuery = True
     .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
     .SavePassword = True
     .SaveData = True
     .AdjustColumnWidth = True
     .RefreshPeriod = 0
     .Refresh
 End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `cast` to `DateValue`

Try this:

```
Sub y()

   Dim strConnection As String
   Dim strSQL As String
   Dim qt As QueryTable

   ActiveSheet.Select
   Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

   strConnection = "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=1;RetrieveIds=Yes;" _
& "DATABASE=http://site.com;" _
& "LIST={f2e4dcfd-a899-4df1-a0b4-6b6af502de35};"

  strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [List Name] where [Production Date] > DateValue('06/15/2013')"

  Set qt = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=Array(strConnection), Destination:=Range("a1"), Sql:=strSQL)

  With qt
     .CommandText = Array(strSQL)
     .Name = "Data from SP list"
     .FieldNames = True
     .RowNumbers = False
     .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
     .PreserveFormatting = True
     .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
     .BackgroundQuery = True
     .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
     .SavePassword = True
     .SaveData = True
     .AdjustColumnWidth = True
     .RefreshPeriod = 0
     .Refresh
 End With

End Sub
```